# positive vs negative class selection

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a NN model performing binary classification on a data set skewed 85/15. Does it matter which class is considered negative vs positive?

Comment: Doesn't matter, they're both equivalent. Related answer, for the case of multiclass classification (or binary classification using softmax outputs): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260017/softmax-multiclass-classification/260038#260038

Comment: Did you consider running the model with one method of coding the classes and then again using the other method?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely arbitrary. Consider that you have a vector $y\in\{0,1\}^n$. The cross-entropy loss is

$$
L = -\sum_i y_i \log(\hat{y}_i) + (1-y_i)\log(1 - \hat{y}_i)
$$

Consider what happens if you switch all of the labels so that 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1. Instead, we have

$$
L = -\sum_i (1-y_i) \log(\hat{y}_i) + y_i \log(1 - \hat{y}_i)
$$

But since $\hat{y}_i$ is the quantity under estimation by the model, it will also "flip". We know that it *must* flip because we're **reducing the loss,** so instead of samples labeled 1 having $\hat{y}_i$ near 1, they will be near 0 instead (and vice versa), leaving us with

$$
L = -\sum_i (1-y_i) \log(1-\hat{y}_i) + y_i \log(\hat{y}_i)
$$

This final expression is, clearly, the same as the first expression.

Conclusion: labels are arbitrary when using this loss function.